# Define properties with Object.defineProperties

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype

Please, help to understand why is the line `obj['prop'] = 'zzz';` doesn't work and even shows error when `"use strict";` is on and works fine when `Object.defineProperty(obj, 'prop', {value:'zzz'});` is used? (While `delete` works absolutely fine)

```
       //"use strict";

        var obj = Object.defineProperties({}, {
            prop: {
                value: 'aaa',
                writeable: true,
                enumerable: true,
                configurable: true
            }
        });

        console.log(obj.prop);
        obj['prop'] = 'zzz';
        //Object.defineProperty(obj, 'prop', {value:'zzz'});
        console.log(obj.prop);
        //delete obj.prop;
        //console.log(obj.prop);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its `writable`, not `writeable` (notice no `e` in the middle).

See MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties#Parameters